# Debian - static ip, /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, debian, interface, static-ip, ifconfig

I tried to set a static IP on my Debian 8.1 (in VirtualBox), so I edited the **/etc/network/interface** file :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.51
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

This configuration seems correct (I also tried without 'auto eth0') and the ip is not already used in the network.

However, when I check with ifconfig, eth0 does not appear, there is obviously an error in my configuration.

ifconfig without interfaces edit (normal) :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4a:58:ae  
          inet addr:192.168.1.43  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4a:58ae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2201 (2.1 KiB)  TX bytes:10924 (10.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4573 (4.4 KiB)  TX bytes:4573 (4.4 KiB)
```

ifconfig with interfaces edit (abnormal) :

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4573 (4.4 KiB)  TX bytes:4573 (4.4 KiB)
```

I would like to know how to configure this eth0 interface to get a static ip.

Comment: After you've configured the interfaces file and restarted networking, will `ifup eth0` bring it up for you?

Comment: Have you tried reboot or combination of: `ifdown --verbose eth0`, `ifconfig eth0 inet 0.0.0.0 down`, `ifup --verbose eth0`? Show us the output of these commands.

Comment: @Safado @sam_pan_mariusz `ifup --verbose eth0` or `ifdown --verbose eth0` **shows the following error** :ifup: couldn't `read interfaces:2: misplaced option`. `ifconfig eth0 inet 0.0.0.0 down` **shows nothing**

Comment: It's complaining about line 2 in your interfaces file. Is what you pasted above the entire file? Or is their more text that you didn't paste here?

Answer (score 1):

There might be more in your file (as Safado above notes) that you did not include, and that might be at fault. Is there a header perhaps that you have accidentally pulled onto two lines that is incorrectly formatted?